# iOS "hold down" radial menu doesn't receive events without raising finger first

Tags: ios, uikit

I've implemented a popup menu in iOS (it's a kind of radial menu), using a long press on my background view to trigger it.

I have a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` attached to my background view; When the recogniser fires, I show the popup menu.
The popup menu is implemented as new view, which I add to the `window` as a subview, and I centre it's location on the touch co-ordinate.

This gives a nice radial popup menu, which works well, but currently it only works if you release the touch after the menu appears, and then tap on the menu itself to action a button.

What I'd like to do, is have a long press (or 3d touch) to show the menu, then be able to drag my finger over to one of the menu buttons and release it in a single action.

I've implemented `onTouchEnd` and `onTouchMove` in my radial menu view, but it only receives these events after I release my finger from the initial long press. It seems like the events get "stuck" to the long press view and don't propagate to the new view which has just appeared over the touch point.

Is there any way I can allow touch move and end events to propagate to my new view without having to release my finger from the screen first, so I can use the menu without releasing my finger from the screen?

Comment: this may be a silly question since you're likely more skilled than I am, but have you attempted to implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` between your long press and the gesture recognizers on the menu?

Comment: You're very humble. Skill is relative to the area being worked in; When it comes to gesture recognisers, right now I'm not very skilled at all! I'll try the suggestion out. Thanks!

Comment: I've implemented this, but it doesn't help; My popup view isn't implementing any gesture recognisers, only responding to `touchEnd` events. As such, there isn't another recogniser for it to work simultaneously with.

Comment: i'm sorry, it hadn't registered in my mind that your radial view listens for touches directly without using a swipe gesture. i believe gesture recognizers intercept the touch events from traveling along the responder chain, handling the identification of the correct view themselves).you could perhaps try to write a custom gesture recognizer for your radial view that responds to the onTouchEnd and onTouchMove, though another long press gesture recognizer might already suffice for your purposes